# Getting LP relaxation solution values

Tags: python, optimization, mixed-integer-programming, scip

To get the final solution after optimization in pyscipopt, we can do

```
# define x to be a vector of x_ij variables
model.data = x
model.optimize()
X = model.getVal(x)
```

I would like to get the LP relaxation solutions at every node of the branch and bound tree. One method for doing this would be to use `model.getVal(t_x_ij)` for every (transformed) variable  'x_ij'. Is there a more efficient way of doing this than looping over all the transformed variables?
Please let me know if you need any further clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are solving a MIP, you would need to get the LP solution values *during* the solving process. You need to implement a callback that is executed whenever a new node LP is solved.

You might want to check out [TreeD](https://github.com/mattmilten/TreeD), a project I created to inspect and visualize various LP-related information during the MIP solving process of [PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt).